# Why another user is required to run hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a question regarding hadoop configuration
why we need to create a user for running hadoop can we not run hadoop on a root user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can run it as `root`.

It is not a requirement to have a dedicated user for Hadoop but having one with lesser privileges than `root` is considered a good practice. It helps in separating Hadoop processes from other services running on the same machine.

Answer (score 4):

This is not hadoop specific, it's a common good practice in IT to have specific users for running daemons ,for security reasons (for example in hadoop, if you run map reduce daemons as root, a malign  user could launch a map reduce job which deletes not only hdfs data, but operating system data), for best control ,etc. Take a look at this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29159/why-is-it-recommended-to-create-a-group-and-user-for-some-applications

Answer (score 3):

It is not at all required to create a new user to run hadoop. Also, hadoop user need not be (should not be) in sudoers file or a root user [[ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431626/should-hadoop-user-be-in-sudoers-file). Your login user for the machine can also act as a hadoop user. But as mentioned by @Luis and @franklinsijo, it is a good practice to have a specific user for a specific service.